# How do you a preprocess statement for #include

Tags: preprocessor

The following seems to do nothing and I'm not sure why. I have the following lines at the top of my code with SOME_FUNCTION also defined of course. Can you do something like this for another directive of include?

```
#if SOME_FUNCTION(4,3,0)
#include "myfile.hh"
#else
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call function in preprocessor! The only method to do something like this is to define pre-build command (.exe call) which may re-define .h or .c files.